# pydantic: field ordering on .model_dump()

Tags: pydantic

When I call `my_model.model_dump()` I need the fields to be ordered in a specific way.

Pydantic has [rules](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev-v1/usage/models/#field-ordering) for how fields are ordered. However my issue is I have a `computed_field` that I need to be dumped before other non-computed fields. Pydantic seems to place this computed field last no matter what I do.

In the example below I need the `computed_field` `foobar` to come before `buzz`.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    foo: str
    bar: str
    buzz: str

    @computed_field
    @property
    def foobar(self) -> str:
        return self.foo + self.bar


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_model = MyModel(foo="foo", bar="bar", buzz="buzz")
    print(my_model.model_dump())
```

```
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar', 'buzz': 'buzz', 'foobar': 'foobar'}
```

**How can I get `foobar` to appear before `buzz` in the dumped model?**